# Are C constant character strings always null terminated?

Tags: c, string

Are C constant character strings always null terminated without exception?

For example, will the following C code always print "true":

```
const char* s = "abc";
if( *(s + 3) == 0 ){
   printf( "true" );
} else {
   printf( "false" );
}
```

Comment: the answer is yes

Comment: I think you mean `if( *(s + 3) == '\0' )`

Comment: Yes - although your question sounds like you suspect otherwise...

Comment: Yes, all string in C are represented by string 0 terminated.

Comment: @AditiRawat '\0' is just a char with value 0, it can be checked against 0.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A string is only a *string* if it contains a null character.

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.  C11 §7.1.1 1

`"abc"` is a *string literal*.  It also always contains a null character.  A *string literal* may contain more than 1 null character.

```
"def\0ghi"  // 2 null characters.
```

In the following, though, `x` is not a string (it is an array of `char` without a *null character*).  `y` and `z` are both arrays of `char` and both are strings.

```
char x[3] = "abc";
char y[4] = "abc";
char z[] = "abc";
```

---

With OP's code, `s` points to a *string*, the string literal `"abc"`, `*(s + 3)` and `s[3]` have the value of 0.  To attempt to modified `s[3]` is undefined behavior as 1) `s` is a `const char *` and 2) the data pointed to by `s` is a *string literal*.  Attempting to modify a *string literal* is also undefined behavior.

```
const char* s = "abc";
```

---

Deeper: C does not define "constant character strings".

The language defines a *string literal*, like `"abc"` to be a character array of size 4 with the value of `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'\0'`.  Attempting to modify these is UB.  How this is used depends on context.

The *standard C library* defines *string*.

With `const char* s = "abc";`, `s` is a *pointer* to data of type `char`.  As a `const some_type *` pointer, using `s` to modify data is UB.  `s` is *initialized* to point to the *string literal* `"abc"`.  `s` itself is not a *string*.  The memory `s` initial points to is a *string*.

Comment: I think in the first case above, x is not guaranteed to be null terminated. (see Felix's answer below)

Comment: @TylerDurden This is what is written here. `x` is not a string, as it *guaranteed not to be terminated*.

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes `x[]` is not null character terminated and so not a _string_, yet `"abc"` is still null character terminated.  Of course its use in `char x[3] = "abc";` renders _that_ `"abc"` null character unneeded as it is not used.

Answer (score 14):

In short, yes. A *string constant* is of course a *string* and a string is by definition 0-terminated.

If you use a string constant as an array initializer like this:

```
char x[5] = "hello";
```

you won't have a 0 terminator in `x` simply because there's no room for it.

But with

```
char x[] = "hello";
```

it will be there and the size of `x` is 6.

Comment: It's just that in the first example it's not the *string constant* which will not have the terminator, but the resulting array.

Comment: Ok, is this language standard specified that constant char strings are null terminated, or is it merely a convention?

Comment: This is language standard. There is no *conventions* not mandated by a standard defining the language behavior.

Comment: @EugeneSh. but that's what I wrote?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah. I mean the question was actually about string constants. So the actual answer is in the first line. The others is just a useful addition.

Answer (score 2):

The notion of a string is determinate as a sequence of characters terminated by zero character. It is not important whether the sequence is modifiable or not that is whether a corresponding declaration has the qualifier `const` or not.

For example string literals in C have types of non-constant character arrays. So you may write for example

```
char *s = "Hello world";
```

In this declaration the identifier `s` points to the first character of the string.

You can initialize a character array yourself by a string using a string literal. For example

```
char s[] = "Hello world";
```

This declaration is equivalent to

```
char s[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0' };
```

However in C you may exclude the terminating zero from an initialization of a character array.

For example

```
char s[11] = "Hello world";
```

Though the string literal used as the initializer contains the terminating zero it is excluded from the initialization. As result the character array `s` does not contain a string.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there isn't really a "string" datatype like in C++ and Java.

Important principle that every competent computer science degree program should mention: Information is symbols *plus interpretation*.

A "string" is defined conventionally as any sequence of characters ending in a null byte ('\0').

The "gotcha" that's being posted (character/byte arrays with the value 0 in the middle of them) is only a difference of interpretation. Treating a byte array as a string versus treating it as bytes (numbers in [0, 255]) has different applications. Obviously if you're printing to the terminal you might want to print characters until you reach a null byte. If you're saving a file or running an encryption algorithm on blocks of data you will need to support 0's in byte arrays.

It's also valid to take a "string" and optionally interpret as a byte array.