# Stack overflow when passing a vector to memcpy

Tags: c++, vector, stack-overflow, memcpy

I am trying to pass a vector of `unsigned char` (shellcode) to virtualalloc but keep getting stack overflow when trying to execute

```cpp
    std::vector<unsigned char> decrypted = {0x00, 0x15, ...} ; //  shell code decrypted to unsigned char
    cout << &decrypted.front() << endl;
    size_t shellcodesize = decrypted.size();
    void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, shellcodesize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    memcpy(exec, &decrypted.front(), shellcodesize);
    ((void(*)())exec)();
```

The shellcode is not the problem because I used different shellcodes all cause the same problem
The encryption/decryption works as intended because it is tested in other projects before and works flawlessly which leaves me with the last 4-5 lines shown above

when compiling no errors are shown but when running in windbg preview I get this

```
(3cd4.3664): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
WARNING: Stack overflow detected. The unwound frames are extracted from outside normal stack bounds.
00000000`00170003 385c7838        cmp     byte ptr [rax+rdi*2+38h],bl ds:00000000`01f13078=??
WARNING: Stack overflow detected. The unwound frames are extracted from outside normal stack bounds.
```

I think that when using `unsigned char buf[] = "\x00\x15";` it is automatically null-terminated but as far as I know a vector is not which I think causes the stack overflow issue (please correct me if wrong )

Comment: For “I think that .. is automatically null terminated”, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47288965/2864740 and note the example given with `z`. This could also be verified by checking the sizeof the array (should have 3 elements, with the last element of 0).

Answer (score 2):

There is one slight issue with your code:

```
void *exec = VirtualAlloc(0, shellcodesize, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

is the correct call to VirtualAlloc here. Most Windows versions actually return allocated memory, if the first parameter is 0, but there is no guarantee for this. If the first parameter is non-0 (and MEM_COMMIT is requested w/o MEM_RESERVE), the call will fail.

Other than that, your code is correct (you might check the return value of VirtualAlloc to be non-zero) and I would suspect, that the loaded code contains the stack overflow. Especially, as `0x00 0x15` does not make any sense at all when disassembled and will certainly crash your application.

**EDIT**: If your architecture is X64, you can test the following shellcode:  `0xb8, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc3` (it simply returns 1 from the subroutine)

Comment: I tired it, I no longer get stack over flow but no shellcode execution happened I used different shellcodes including the one provided

Comment: You can test my shellcode by casting exec to a int return value and evaluating the returned integer. It should be 1. The value returned is actually the second value in my shellcode. You can excahnge the 0x01 by a 5 there for example and see the returned value in your code.

Comment: Can you show your shellcode and the disassembly? Have you put your shellcode in a disassembler and checked, that it's valid binary assembly code?

Comment: the shellcode I used was generated from a tool cloned from github and i tested it with other methods and it worked fine but not with this method